# Yii Crud in not completing

Tags: yii, crud

For the table users, I have written like

yiic shell
model users (it works)
crud users

The last line does not finish

```
>> crud users
  unchanged UseersController.php
  unchanged UsersTest.php
  unchanged create.php
  unchanged update.php
  unchanged index.php
  unchanged view.php
```

...then it hangs

So when I go to qdr/index.php?r=words/create

it shows some error like

WordsController cannot find the requested view "_form".

C:\xampp\htdocs\qdr\framework\web\CController.php(878)

The result is supposed to be like-

```
>> crud User
   generate UserController.php
   generate UserTest.php
   mkdir D:/testdrive/protected/views/user
   generate create.php
   generate update.php
   generate index.php
   generate view.php
   generate admin.php
   generate _form.php
   generate _view.php
```

so the _form.php, _view.php etc is not created.

Why is this? Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its deprecated  use gii instead. referring you a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lyg9qIH7oQ

Please Watch and use.

Thanks